# Count of specific case per row in matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am fairly new to numpy and scientific computing and I struggle with a problem for several days, so I decided to post it here.

I am trying to get a count for a specific occurence of a condition in a numpy array.

```
In [233]: import numpy as np

In [234]: a= np.random.random([5,5])

In [235]: a >.7
Out[235]: array([[False,  True,  True, False, False],
   [ True, False, False, False,  True],
   [ True, False,  True,  True, False],
   [False, False, False, False, False],
   [False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

What I would like to count the number of occurence of `True` in each row and keep the rows when this count reach a certain threshold:

ex :

```
results=[]
threshold = 2

for i,row in enumerate(a>.7):
  if len([value for value in row if value==True]) > threshold:
     results.append(i) # keep ids for each row that have more than 'threshold' times True
```

This is the non-optimized version of the code but I would love to achieve the same thing with numpy (I have a very large matrix to process).

I have been trying all sort of things with `np.where` but I only can get flatten results. I need the row number

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make results reproducible, use some seed:

```
>>> np.random.seed(100)
```

Then for a sample matrix

```
>>> a = np.random.random([5,5])
```

Count number of occurences along axis with sum:

```
>>> (a >.7).sum(axis=1)
array([1, 0, 3, 1, 2])
```

You can get row numbers with `np.where`:

```
>>> np.where((a > .7).sum(axis=1) >= 2)
(array([2, 4]),)
```

To filter result, just use boolean indexing:

```
>>> a[(a > .7).sum(axis=1) >= 2]
array([[ 0.89041156,  0.98092086,  0.05994199,  0.89054594,  0.5769015 ],
       [ 0.54468488,  0.76911517,  0.25069523,  0.28589569,  0.85239509]])
```

Comment: Extracting the indices with `where` is unnecessary, you can use the boolean array to index the rows directly, i.e. `a[(a > .7).sum(axis=1) >= 2]` should do the same, and boolean indexing tends to be the fastest.

Comment: @Jamie, thanks for noting. I was mislead by `where` in OP question.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum over axis with `a.sum`.
Then you can use where on the resulting vector.

```
results = np.where(a.sum(axis=0) < threshold))
```